# Count occurrences of two NumPy arrays having given items at corresponding indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two NumPy arrays as below:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1])
b = np.array([4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3])
```

I want to count how many times an item `2` is encountered in the array `a` with the condition that the array `b` had items `4` at corresponding indices:

```
a = np.array([2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1])
b = np.array([4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3])
              ↑        ↑        ↑
```

As you can see there are 3 such cases. How do I calculate that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it as follows:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1])
b = np.array([4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3])
result = ((a == 2) & (b == 4)).sum()
print(result)
# 3
```

---

`a == 2` and `b == 4` will make boolean arrays with `True` values when the items equal 2 and 4 respectively:

```
>>> a == 2
array([ True, False, False,  True, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False])
>>> b == 4
array([ True, False,  True,  True, False, False,  True, False,  True, False])
```

By using the logical and operator `&` in `(a == 2) & (b == 4)` we will get a boolean array with `True` for those positions where both items are `True`:

```
>>> (a == 2) & (b == 4)
array([ True, False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False, False])
```

and to count the total number of `True` values we can just use the [`sum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.sum.html) method.

---

References:

- [Indexing and slicing](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/absolute_beginners.html#indexing-and-slicing)
- [Boolean or “mask” index arrays](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays)